How do I access a project's package registry from within that projects CI/CD pipeline in Gitlab?
I am trying to set up my project's CI/CD pipeline in GitLab and I am getting stuck at every turn. I am attempting to access package dependencies that are housed within the project in GitLab's package repository, because a few of the .jar files we need are not located within Maven's central repo. I keep getting a '401 Unauthorized' error no matter how I configure my settings, pom, and yaml file. I'm fairly new to this, so I'm sure there's something silly I'm missing, but I'm just not seeing it. The full error is below. I'm replacing references to company/project names with dummies but everything else is copy pasted from the trace.

Failed to execute goal on project foo: Could not resolve dependencies for project foo:bar:jar:0.4.0: Failed to collect dependencies at gov.nasa:worldwind:jar:2.2.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for gov.nasa:worldwind:jar:2.2.1: Could not transfer artifact gov.nasa:worldwind:pom:2.2.1 from/to gitlab-maven (http://gitlab.lan.foobar.com/api/v4/projects/6/packages/maven): authentication failed for http://gitlab.lan.foobar.com/api/v4/projects/6/packages/maven/gov/nasa/worldwind/2.2.1/worldwind-2.2.1.pom, status: 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]

I have found the ci job token and am trying to use that in my settings and pom, but that has not fixed the issue. I've tried different configurations to get it to work, but to no avail.
I will include the relevant parts of the pom and settings files below.
Here is the relevant part of the pom.xml file.
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>http://gitlab.lan.foobar.com/api/v4/projects/6/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>http://gitlab.lan.foobar.com/api/v4/projects/6/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>http://gitlab.lan.foobar.com/api/v4/projects/6/packages/maven</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

And now the relevant part of the ci_settings.xml file. Note* I have tried the ci_settings file with both of the server configurations shown below. Separately and together at the same time. None of the three configurations has given results.
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <configuration>
                <httpHeaders>
                    <property>
                        <name>Job-Token</name>
                        <value>${CI_JOB_TOKEN}</value>
                    </property>
                </httpHeaders>
            </configuration>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <username>Job-Token</username>
            <password>${CI_JOB_TOKEN}</password>
            <configuration>
                <authenticationInfo>
                    <userName>Job-Token</userName>
                    <password>${CI_JOB_TOKEN}</password>
                </authenticationInfo>
            </configuration>
        </server>
    </servers>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>http://gitlab.lan.foobar.com/api/v4/projects/6/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

And now the ci.yml file. Note* I have tried the yaml file in multiple configurations as well. Changed the order, commented out some things, etc. None of which have provided results.
include:
  - template: Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml

variables:
  MAVEN_SETTINGS_PATH: "ci_settings.xml"
  MAVEN_CUSTOM_GOALS: "dependency:resolve"
  AUTO_DEVOPS_BUILD_IMAGE_CNB_BUILDER: "heroku/builder:22"
  AUTO_DEVOPS_BUILD_IMAGE_FORWARDED_CI_VARIABLES: "DEPLOY_TOKEN_PASS,MAVEN_SETTINGS_PATH"
  AUTO_DEVOPS_BUILD_IMAGE_CNB_ENABLED: "true"
  JAVA_HOME: "*/openjdk-21.0.2"

deploy:
  image: maven:3.9.5-jdk-21
  before_script:
    - git config --global url.“https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.lan.foobar.com”.insteadOf "https://gitlab.lan.foobar.com"
  script:
  - 'mvn deploy -s ci_settings.xml'
  rules:
   - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

#build:
#  before_script:
#    - export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
#    - git config --global url.“https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.lan.foobar.com”.insteadOf "https://gitlab.lan.foobar.com"


You will likely have to create an access token on the project that has the package registry.  The CI_JOB_TOKEN isn't scoped to be able to get packages from the package registry.
